# Get Company References by using LinkedIn for iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, linkedin-api

In my native iOS App, If user will Sign in with LinkedIn then I want to get references of that specific user.
For example, If user wants to apply in XYZ company then i want to get user's all references that are already working in XYZ company. Can it be possible by using provided LinkedIn APIs or with any other way?

Suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just come up with one solution that i want to share with all of you.

Call Connections API call with the required fields that you needed.
For example, you need following fields:

1. id
2. first-name
3. last-name
4. headline
5. picture-url

**Now URL will be look like following:**
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url)?oauth2_access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

**Response will be look like following:**

```
<person>
<id>rXoyP_RKnr</id>
<first-name>First Name</first-name>
<last-name>Last Name</last-name>
<headline>Designation at Company</headline>
<picture-url>http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_MC0ebCSKkfIunfunUiMRb3opkDY2qfjnc6Icb3whUHEjIwo9zkfkdT0aE_O-BHpsZTjneQM-h6tR</picture-url>
</person>
```